# Terraform: CodeBuild Error BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE: Incorrect username or password

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild, aws-secrets-manager

I am provisioning codebuild project with terraform. `This codebuild project will use docker image of terraform.` as I need to run terraform commands inside the container.

My workflow.

- Created secrets for login credentials of docker hub in secrets manger.
- setup configuration for secrets in codebuild configuration.

Here is my code build config.

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "tf-plan" {
  name         = "tf-cicd-plan"
  description  = "Plan stage for terraform"
  service_role = aws_iam_role.codebuild_role.arn

  artifacts {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }

  #   cache {
  #     type     = "S3"
  #     location = aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket
  #   }

  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "hashicorp/terraform:1.3.5"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "SERVICE_ROLE"
    registry_credential {
      credential          = var.dockerhub_credentials
      credential_provider = "SECRETS_MANAGER"
    }
  }
```

codebuild_iam.tf

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "codebuild_role_policy" {
  statement {
    sid       = ""
    actions   = ["logs:*", "s3:*", "codebuild:*", "secretsmanager:*", "iam:*"]
    resources = ["*"]
    effect    = "Allow"
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "dockerhub_credentials" {
  type = string
}
```

terraform.tfvars

```
dockerhub_credentials = "<secrets manager arn>"
```

Upon running the build stage it fails with an incorrect username or password error. though credentials are absolutely fine.

Comment: Is there the same image you want here: https://gallery.ecr.aws/? Because otherwise you might hit the rate limit on Docker hub at some point.

Comment: I didn't know about this thank you, what are the benefits of choosing ECR Public repo over docker ( one would be rate limit )

Comment: The second being it's hosted in AWS. :) So probably faster download times.

Comment: But: does your IAM role have permissions to read from the Secrets Manager?